# NGINX: proxy_pass for a dynamic url

Tags: nginx, proxy, redirect

I have a docker container which serves a web application on:

```
my.server.domain:8080
```

When I request that URL with a browser, it is automatically redirected to the login page:

```
http://my.server.domain:8080/login
```

I'm trying to proxy the app so that I can avoid to use the port number.
Two possible ways to achieve that are:

1)  http://my.server.domain/appname

2)  http://appname.my.server.domain

Either way, will work for me. 
But I'm struggling with making the right NGINX configuration.

I tried with:

```
    location /appname {
            proxy_pass             http://my.server.domain:8080/;
    }
```

But when I load `http://my.server.domain/appname` it gets redirected to `http://my.server.domain/login` which doesn't exist.

If I use `/` it works as expected:

```
    location / {
            proxy_pass             http://my.server.domain:8080/;
    }
```

But that's not what I need.

I can add more directives like:

```
    location /login {
            proxy_pass             http://my.server.domain:8080/login;
    }
```

But then it will fail on the next redirect and so on ..

Comment: Option (2) is simplest solution. But your current problem is rewriting redirects which is tricky but solvable using one or more [proxy_redirect](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) statements.

Comment: seems I can use option (2) adding a new server directive  `server_name appname.domain.net;` and then use a proxy for its root location `/` with `proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;`  option (1) is still unclear how to combine proxy_pass, rewrite and proxy_redirect so to be able to use: domain.net/appname  instead of appname.domain.net

Comment: Option (1) is dependent on the application - many applications load resources (css & js) relative to the root, so cause problems when you try to force them into a subdirectory. `nginx` can rewrite redirects, but not each and every URL in the HTML source.

Comment: In my case the application needs to load resource. So I guess it will be hard to use option (2).  The web app I'm trying to serve is: https://github.com/sharelatex/sharelatex which uses docker compose. There are some options in the docker-compose file which allow the use of NGINX but is not clear what/how configure the whole app. For now the "subdomain" solution seems to be the most convinient way.